# How to extract text between square brackets in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace, extract

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @value as nvarchar(max)
SET @value   = '(company.[department] LIKE ''Development'')';
```

I would like to extract the word between brackets keep it in a value and then put as input in a replace function like this.

```
select replace(@value, @department, 'another_string');
```

You will say probably why I don't do it immediately with the replace function.
The case is that this department string may change dynamically to another string for example country and I would like every time to keep this choice and change it with a value.

Comment: Use a `SUBSTRING` with 2 `CHARINDEX`, one with [ and another with ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your particular case will idealy works with `parsename`function:

```
DECLARE @value as nvarchar(max), @department varchar(100);
SET @value = '(company.[department] LIKE ''Development'')';
SET @department = parsename(replace(replace(@value,'[','.'),']','.'),2)

SELECT replace(@value, @department, 'another_string');
```

will return:

```
(company.[another_string] LIKE 'Development')
```

---

explanation:

replace brackets with dot '.' and your @value will looks like this:

`(company..department. LIKE 'Development')`

such pattern is similar with:

`Server name`.`Database name`.`Schema name`.`Object name`

and you can extract the part of string using `parsename` function, where: `1 = Object name`, `2 = Schema name`, `3 = Database name`, `4 = Server name`

link to function here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/CCWU34572)**

Answer (score 13):

You can do this in a query via the base string functions:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col,
              CHARINDEX('[', col) + 1,
              CHARINDEX(']', col) - CHARINDEX('[', col) - 1) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Caveats include that you only have one bracketed term, and also that this query form of an answer would be usable in your particular scenario.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Try like following.

```
DECLARE @value as nvarchar(max) 
SET @value = '(company.[department] LIKE ''Development'')'; 
declare @department NVARCHAR(100) 
SELECT @department = Substring(@value, 
                       Charindex('[', @value) + 1, 
                       Charindex(']', @value) - 
                       Charindex('[', @value) - 1) 

select Replace(@value, @department, 'another_string');
```

**Output**

```
(company.[another_string] LIKE 'Development')
```